# What went wrong with my Declare statement?

Tags: vb6, winapi, declare

I've recently fixed a bug in a VB6 application, but I'm not sure, what exactly went wrong.

The offending part was a wrong API declaration of `CreateEvent`. This is, what API Viewer generated:

```
Declare Function CreateEvent Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateEventA" 
(lpEventAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, ...) As Long
```

The next one is the **wrong** declare, obviously someone didn't want to import the `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` structure...

```
Declare Function CreateEvent Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateEventA" 
(lpEventAttributes As Any, ...) As Long
```

The call was:

```
Event = CreateEvent(Nothing, 0, 0, "MyEventName")
```

This call worked *always* in the IDE, but *never* from the compiled .exe. (`CreateEvent` always returned 0)

I changed the declaration to:

```
Declare Function CreateEvent Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateEventA" 
(ByVal lpEventAttributes As Any, ...) As Long
```

... and it worked.

Now I'm a little bit puzzled:

- Why is the parameter `ByRef` when using `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` but must be `ByVal` when using `Any`?
- Why did the wrong declare always work in the IDE?

Comment: `ByVal ... As Any` is the most bizarre case of parameter declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use an unqualified As Any parameter, you have to be explicit in the Call. This should have fixed the problem:

```
Event = CreateEvent(ByVal 0&, 0, 0, "MyEventName")
```

I can't see why you'd use `Nothing` here, since that's an Object reference and the call is expecting a pointer. What `ByVal 0&` does is pass a null pointer -- since it's null it doesn't matter what it's (not) pointing to. But passing `Nothing ByVal` probably forces `ByVal 0&`, which is why it worked.

As to why it worked in the IDE, well, the IDE does tend to be more forgiving about things like this.